# get curent class in sidebar ($_GET['do'] == "")

Tags: php

In my sidebar is class added for active link with this code:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['do'] == "") ? "class=\"current\"": "";?>

// This is root link
```

All working but I have error in my error_log file....

This is in next menu item:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['do'] == "add_account") ? "class=\"current\"": "";?>
```

Also working but without error!! So I need something add into "" ?Or how can I better make root link mark in menu with php ?

Thanks for opinions!!
Regards
Makromat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing variables (or array indexes, or object properties) which do not exist (yet) in PHP triggers a `Notice` (not an error). This is the case when you access `$_GET['do']`, which does not exist.

In order to fix that, replace:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['do'] == "") ? "class=\"current\"": "";?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo !isset($_GET['do']) ? "class=\"current\"": "";?>
```

The same applies everywhere a variable (or array index, or object property) which *might* not exist. So when you're checking `$_GET['do']` for equality with either `""` or `"add_account"` you need to first check if `isset($_GET['do'])`.

Which means you also need to edit the second occurrence of `$_GET['do']` in your code:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['do'] == "add_account") ? "class=\"current\"": "";?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php echo (isset($_GET['do']) AND $_GET['do'] == "add_account") ? "class='current'" : ""; ?>
```

Like @Houssni said.

Comment: thats the oposit of what one asked for

Comment: @tinyByte This actually makes sense and could very well be what's going on. The OP did mention something about root link, which I assume to be accessing the site without any query string. And if that's the case, he'd see an undefined index error in his log.

Comment: @tinyByte no, it's not, he's saying that `$_GET['do'] == ""` yields an error (actually a notice) while `$_GET['do'] == "add_account"` yields no such error. He's asking what to do so that `$_GET['do'] == ""` would yield no error either.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == "add_account") ? "class='current'" : ""; ?>
```

Check if it exists and **then** check which value it holds.